# Как сохранить Uri изображения в SQLite с последующим использованием

Tags: android, sqlite, изображения

Занимаюсь созданием своего первого андроид-приложения. Идея такая: есть страница с личными данным пользователя + его аватарка. При первом запуске, ставится картинка-заглушка, но пользователь может её поменять, а в БД должно сохраниться Uri изображения, чтобы при последующей загрузке, приложение брало его и подставляло картинку из галереи. 
При первом запуске и выборе картинки из галереи, всё ок  - картинка подставляется. При перезапуске приложения, получаю ошибку.

Код сохранения Uri:

```
            final InputStream imageStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(mUri);
            image_source = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
            //output
            Log.d("Path:",mUri.toString());

            data.put("c_pic",mUri.toString());
            db.update("mdb_table_contacts", data, "c_id=" + 1, null);
```

При перезапуске, пробовал уже разные варианты:

1)

```
 Uri bufUri = Uri.parse(pic_uri);
 image_source = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), bufUri);
```

2)

```
final InputStream imageStream = getContext().getContentResolver().openInputStream(bufUri);
image_source = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
```

Но получаю ошибку:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.eugen.businesscard, PID: 13648
              java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord{26db29e9 13648:com.example.eugen.businesscard/u0a87} (pid=13648, uid=10087) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
                  at
```

При этом содержимое Манифест файла:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS" />
```

Возможно мне стоит иначе как-то сохранять Uri или может быть посоветуете другой способ реализации? Спасибо.

Comment: Для такой работы с картинками есть библиотека - Picasso или Glide, UniversalImageLoader, которая сама  сохраняет в кеш. Посмотри а них, может подойдет тебе.

Comment: Но мне же нужно не в кеш, а чтобы после любого запуска, если пользователь выбрал себе картинку, она ставилась автоматически. Это мне подойдет?

Comment: @Eugen, попробуйте тут посмотреть http://stackoverflow.com/a/25194460/3212712

Comment: Добавил по примеру в onResult метод, но получаю ошибку: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: No persistable permission grants found for UID 10094 and Uri 0 @ content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image:34

Comment: Хорошо, тогда тебе нужно запросить доступ к записи и чтении данных с памяти с помощью runtime permission, в Android >=6, а так сохраняй URI в SQL,  попробуй так, должно получиться)